# Flexbox not displaying images correctly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have a flexbox set up as shown in the snippet, the problem I have is that in Chrome, once the viewport is less than the width of both images, the whole website zooms down and everything is messed up. Everything works fine in Firefox. I've tried everything I could think of and nothing works. Here's a link to my website as well: [airstarkennels.com](https://www.airstarkennels.com/parents)

```css
body {
  background: #000000 url("https://www.airstarkennels.com/images/main-background.jpg") left bottom/cover no-repeat fixed;
}
#first-page-header {
  color: #ff00ee;
  text-align: center;
}
#parents-page-content-wrapper {
  margin: 0 0 2em;
}
#parents-page-mommy-info-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.parents-page-image-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.parents-page-images {
  max-height: 350px;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.parents-page-images:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="parents-page-content-wrapper">
    <h1 id="first-page-header">Parents</h1>
    <div id="parents-page-mommy-info-wrapper">
      <div class="parents-page-image-wrapper">
        <img id="parents-page-mommys-pedigree" class="parents-page-images" src="https://www.airstarkennels.com/images/mommy-pedigree.jpg">
        <img id="parents-page-mommy-image" class="parents-page-images" src="https://www.airstarkennels.com/images/mommy.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Hi, do you want the pictures to sit next to each other on mobile view or on a newline?

Comment: @M.A Shahbazi They should sit next to each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically happening because the overflow of content is being scrolled on chrome in X axis. You can use **CSS Grid** for your images container.
Making your grid container with `display: inline-grid` and since the images can have different width we will use `grid-template-columns: auto auto` for the columns.
So all together its like this:

```css
body {
    background: #000000
        url('https://www.airstarkennels.com/images/main-background.jpg') left
        bottom/cover no-repeat fixed;
}

#first-page-header {
    color: #ff00ee;
    text-align: center;
}

#parents-page-content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 0 2em;
}
#parents-page-mommy-info-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.parents-page-image-wrapper {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    justify-items: space-between;
}

.parents-page-images {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 350px;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.parents-page-images:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div id="parents-page-content-wrapper">
        <h1 id="first-page-header">Parents</h1>
        <div id="parents-page-mommy-info-wrapper">
            <div class="parents-page-image-wrapper">
                <img id="parents-page-mommys-pedigree" class="parents-page-images"
                    src="https://www.airstarkennels.com/images/mommy-pedigree.jpg">
                <img id="parents-page-mommy-image" class="parents-page-images"
                    src="https://www.airstarkennels.com/images/mommy.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Chrome won't display my grid container at all. I didn't dig into it yet, but any ideas?

Comment: @claronic after checking your live website I figured out what you are doing wrong. Simply replace the `.parents-page-images { height: 100%;}` line with `max-height: 350px;` and it works like it should.

Comment: Ya, you're right. I should've thought of that before now. Thanks!